# Read values from dynamic created dictionary keys. - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am reading data from and API whose response is a JSON.

And then is converted to Python Dictionary

Part of that dictionary in question is, list of dictionaries actually.

```
[
    {
      "inputType" : "text",
      "can_be_anything_here" : {
        "label" : "Enter name",
        "value" : "login",
        "required" : "True"
      }
    },
    {
      "inputType" : "password",
      "can_be_anything_here" : {
        "label" : "password",
        "value" : "password",
        "required" : "True"
      }
    }
]
```

Then I have to generate HTML for this form.

I can easily read value on `"inputType"` because its key is know each time.

But I need to read

```
{
  "label" : "password",
  "value" : "password",
  "required" : "True"
}
```

But its key is unknown/dynamic each time `"can_be_anything_here"`

How do I read data from it?

Comment: Other than iterating over the dictionary?

Comment: SOrry what??? 1 thing is for sure that each dictionary will have 2 keys ... first `"inputType"` and second will be `"can_be_anything_here"`

Comment: `for k, v in d.items(): if k != 'inputType': ...`

Comment: Are you saying the keys are different for each response? That seems very unlikely

Comment: yes, `"can_be_anything_here"` can be different each time ... actually that is `id` of HTML element ... will be unique each time

Answer (score 0):

If what i understood from your question is correct. So, the key `can_be_aything_here` is a variable and you want to access to it value's key everytime. If this is what you meant, so here what comes first to my mind:

```
a = [{"inputType": "text", "can_be_anything_here": {"label": "Enter name", "value": "login", "required" : "True"}}, {"inputType": "Password", "can_be_anything_here2": {"label": "password", "value": "password", "required" : "True"}}]

for i in a:
    for k, v in i.items():
        # You can remove this codition if you need this key's value
        if k != "inputType": 
            # Here you can retrive the unkown key
            print("Current Key is: ", k)
            # Here you can have the unknown key value which is a dict
            print(v, type(v))
            # For example: retrive the dict's value of the unknown key  
            print "v['label']: ",  v["label"]
```

Output:

```
Current Key is:  can_be_anything_here
{'required': 'True', 'value': 'login', 'label': 'Enter name'} <type 'dict'>
v['label']:  Enter name
Current Key is:  can_be_anything_here2
{'required': 'True', 'value': 'password', 'label': 'password'} <type 'dict'>
v['label']:  password
```

Answer (score -1):

if each dictionary in the list has only two keys, try

for key in lst[index]:

```
if key != "inputType":

   content = lst[index][key]
```

I think you will be able to read the thing you want.

Comment: I dont know key name of second dic item so your code will not work

Comment: Reread the code carefully, as u know the first key as 'inputType', whatever != 'inputType' must be your second key as your are interacting through all the keys inside that dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

If each dictionary in your list has only two keys, then you just need to check if the key is `inputType` or `something_else`:

```
for i in yourList:
    for key in i:
        if key != 'inputType':
            print(i[key]['label'])
```

Of couse, if each dictionary has more than two keys, you can put all keys' name in a list like this:

```
nameList = ['inputType', 'time', ... ]
```

Just make sure `nameList` excludes `can_be_something_else`. Then what you need to do is to check whether the key in it or not:

```
for i in yourList:
    for key in i:
        if key not in nameList:
            print(i[key]['label'])
```

You can also check whether the value to the key has `label value required` keys to make sure you catch the right part:

```
for i in yourList:
    for key in i:
        if 'label' in i[key] and 'value' in i[key] and 'required' in i[key]:
            print(i[key]['label'])
```